# Using secondary index and key filter together in RIAK mapred

Tags: riak

Is possible to use sec index and key filters together in a map reduce query. Something like this

```
*{"inputs":{ "bucket"     :"ignore_bucket1",
    "index"      :"secindex_bin",
    "key"        :"secIndexVal",
    "key_filters":[["and",
                  [["tokenize", "-", 5], ["greater_than_eq", "20120101"]],
                  [["tokenize", "-", 5], ["less_than_eq", "20120112"]]
    ]]
}}
```

Also is it efficient to get list of keys using sec index and then run keyfilter on returned keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to combine these in the input statement as they represent very different ways of retrieving keys. It would be possible to implement this is as you suggested, by using the secondary index to retrieve the initial set (avoids scan of all keys) and then implement the key filtering logic as a map phase function.

Another, probably faster, way to get around it could perhaps be to create an additional compound binary secondary index, e.g. [secIndexVal]_[date]. If this is ensured to sort correctly, you could run a single secondary index range query on this and get the values you specified above.

Comment: Thanks Christian. Gonna add the date to the sec Index

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you cannot do this through the HTTP api,

As Christian mentioned you can use a range query, but you don't need a alternative index as you already have the primary key index which can be referenced by `$key` as index field:

```
olav@nyx ~ (master *%) » curl http://nyx:8098/riak/test/20120931 -d "31. Sep 2012"
olav@nyx ~ (master *%) » curl http://nyx:8098/riak/test/20121002 -d "02. Oct 2012"
olav@nyx ~ (master *%) » curl http://nyx:8098/riak/test/20121021 -d "21. Oct 2012
olav@nyx ~ (master *%) » curl http://nyx:8098/riak/test/20121102 -d "The future"     
olav@nyx ~ (master *%) » curl -X POST -H "content-type: application/json" \
-d @- http://localhost:8098/mapred \
<<EOF
{ "inputs":{
      "bucket":"test"
    , "index":"\$key"
    , "start":"20121001"
    , "end":"20121101"
}
, "query":[{
      "reduce":{
           "language":"erlang"
         , "module":"riak_kv_mapreduce"
         , "function":"reduce_identity"
         , "keep":true
      }
  }]
}
EOF
# ...
[["test","20121021"],["test","20121002"]]
```

If you really want key filters with you can use Erlang pb client and do something along these lines (you need `riak_kv` in your codepath):

```
{ok, Pid} = riakc_pb_socket:start_link("127.0.0.1", 8087),
Index = {index, <<"test1">>, <<"field_int">>, <<"123">>},
{ok, Filter} = riak_kv_mapred_filters:build_filter([[<<"ends_with">>,"1"]]).
MapReduce = [
   { reduce
  , {qfun, fun(X, F) -> lists:filter(fun({A, B}) -> F(B) end, X) end}
  , riak_kv_mapred_filters:compose(Filter)
  , true}],
riakc_pb_socket:mapred(Pid, Index, MapReduce).
```